# Stored Procedure With Named Parameters And Cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

I was reading on named parameters.  I actually have 2 questions:

If using named parameter syntax:  `p_rank => 5`, can I only pass what I need.  Say the procedure accepts 5 parameters, but for this call, I only want to pass 1 parameter.

Can I:  `exec procedure_name(p_rank => 5)` and not worry about the other 4?

Now with that, how can I use named parameters that have as output a REF CURSOR?

```
exec customer_package.retrieve_data (
  p_rank             => 5,
  p_value_score      => p_value,
  p_momentum_score   => p_momentum,
  p_growth_score     => p_growth,
  p_data             => p_output);
```

p_data is actually a REF CURSOR.......so, if calling using Positional Parameters from SQL Plus I can just define the variable as a REF_CURSOR and print it.  But this is being done in a stored procedure, calling another stored procedure, which is to return a REF CURSOR.......

Comment: Yes, the whole idea of named parameters is to allow you to provide just the ones you need, as long as the other parameters are not required.

Answer (score 3):

To call proc as `exec procedure_name(p_rank => 5)` you should define other parameters with `DEFAULT` values. If you have `OUT` parameters like p_data, you should pass it to your proc anyway.